# Ajax mysql php filter is not working with mysqli function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm using ajax, jquery, mysql and php filter, it is working fine with PDO connectivity but when I'm using MYSQLI connectivity then its not working and not showing any output, My html and ajax code is

index.php

```
<table id="phones">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <!--  <th width="15">ID</th>-->
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="filter">
    <h2>Filter options</h2>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Samsung">
        <label for="Samsung">Samsung</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="iPhone">
        <label for="iPhone">iPhone</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="HTC">
        <label for="HTC">HTC</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="LG">
        <label for="LG">LG</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia">
        <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script>
    function makeTable(data){
        var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "",
            currRecord = this;

            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
                if(k==='model'){
                    v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['model'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
                } else if (k==='price'){
                    v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
                }
                tbl_row += "<td>"+ v +"</td>";
            });
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        });

        return tbl_body;
    }

    function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.id);
          }
        });

        return opts;
    }

    function updatePhones(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
            opts = allBrands;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
            updatePrices();
          }
        });
    }

    var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
        updatePhones(opts);
    });


    var allBrands = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
    })

    updatePhones();
    updatePrices();
</script>
```

submit.php (MYSQLI CONNECTIVITY)

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oop");
if(!$con){
    die ("Could not connect to database" . mysqli_connect_errno());
}

$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : '';
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';

$sql="SELECT name, model, price  FROM mobile_phone_name WHERE name IN ($qMarks)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $name = $row['name'];
   $model = $row['model'];
   $price = $row['price'];

   $arr[] = array("name"=>"$name", "price"=>"$price", "model"=>"$model");
}
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

submit.php (PDO CONNECTIVITY)

```
<?php 
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oop', 'root', '');
$opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name, model, price FROM mobile_phone_name WHERE name IN ($qMarks)");
$statement -> execute($opts);
$results = $statement -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always enable error reporting or look into the developers / javascript console which returns useful information. "Does not work" - it's your job to find out the error, and we are here to assist you with a solution.

Comment: Does your mysql stuff work as a stand-alone? Can you run the PHP page?

Comment: Dear @DanFromGermany thanks for your reply, here I'm not getting any error so I post my questing here because am stuck in this question before many hour, and I tried to solve it most time but finally I don not get any solution so I ask it with you, and sorry for my bad english. :(

Comment: @JayBlanchard ya I can run PHP page, so I say here my PDO connectivity is working find but when I tried it with MYSQLI connectivity then its not working so can you help me please?

Comment: You put placeholder `?` in it but don't feed it with data. `echo $sql;` - The SQL statement is wrong too, missing blankspaces and such.

Comment: If you run the page with mysqli and it returns results it is working. Why are you wanting to change to mysqli? What is not working? The query is not running? Please turn on all error reporting and / or look in your error logs.

Comment: That statement is in both versions @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you don't put data in the placeholders of the MySQLi prepared statement:

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : '';
$qMarks = str_repeat('?,', count($opts) - 1) . '?';

$sql="SELECT name, model, price  FROM mobile_phone_name WHERE name IN ($qMarks)";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

Where is `$opts` used ?

It works something like this (not tested tho):

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
foreach ($opts as $v) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $v);
}
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch())
```

Type mismatch:

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : '';
```

must be

```
$opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @DanFromGermany, ya you are right I forgot to add $opts but I'm confuse where should I used $opts can you suggest me where should I used $opts, thank you and you reply will be appreciate.

Comment: I did suggest how to use it in my answer.